# PHP foreach Construct Confusion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the `foreach` construct. I have found numerous examples of course, but I never seem to be able to adapt them to my needs.

Please consider this working example I have:

I am collecting two dates in an HTML form:

```
<form method="post">
    <legend>Minutes and Records</legend>

    <label for="FirstAGMDate">First AGM Date (only if known)</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstAGMDate" value="2014-01-01" />

    <label for="MinutesInspectedFromDate">Minutes Inspected From Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="MinutesInspectedFromDate" value="2014-01-02" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

On submit the values are being pushed to the mysql database with a PDO prepared statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE jobsinglevalues SET Date = :FirstAGMDate WHERE FormId = 0; 
            UPDATE jobsinglevalues SET Date = :MinutesInspectedFromDate WHERE FormId = 1;";
    $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':FirstAGMDate'=>($_POST['FirstAGMDate']), ':MinutesInspectedFromDate'=>($_POST['MinutesInspectedFromDate'])));
}
```

This works no problem, but it's not very clever when I need to repeat this for a dozen inputs. What I want to do is achieve this with only one line of sql; looping for each `<input type="text" name="Value" />`.

How can I place this into a `foreach` loop?

*In my head* it works like this:

On submit each input updates the value in the database based on `FormId`, which increments by 1 each loop starting at 0. `FormId` is not a primary key, it simply mirrors the order in which the form elements are displayed.

**Update - working example**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$FormId = 0;
    foreach($_POST['Value'] as $avalue){
        $sql = "UPDATE jobsinglevalues SET Date = :Value WHERE FormId = :FormId";
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array(':Value'=>($avalue), ':FormId'=>($FormId)));
        ++$FormId;
    }
}
```

This seems to logically work to me! Is the correct solution similar? Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Thankyou,

Sam

Comment: First, you'd need to get an array of values from the post, so instead of `<input name="Value">` use `<input name="Value[]">`. Then you can use `foreach($_POST['Value'] as $avalue){ ... }` where you use the `$avalue` variable for the statements in the `foreach`.

Comment: this should be an answer..

Comment: @towr Perfect! That makes sense to me (!) and works a treat. Please post as an answer so I can upvote and mark this as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by making sure all our values are in an array after posted; if you don't care about the keys you can just use `name="Values[]"`, but I'll use `name="Value[FirstAGMDate]"` etc so we know what key a value belongs to.

```
<form method="post">
    <legend>Minutes and Records</legend>

    <label for="FirstAGMDate">First AGM Date (only if known)</label>
    <input type="text" id="FirstAGMDate" name="Value[FirstAGMDate]" value="2014-01-01" />

    <label for="MinutesInspectedFromDate">Minutes Inspected From Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="MinutesInspectedFromDate" name="Value[MinutesInspectedFromDate]" value="2014-01-02" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Now we can process the posted array of values. If we want to do something with the key, we can use `foreach($_POST['Value'] as $akey => $avalue)`, if we are only interested in the values then `foreach($_POST['Value'] as $avalue)` suffices.

```
$sql = "UPDATE jobsinglevalues SET Date = :Value WHERE FormId = :FormId;";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST['Value'] as $akey => $avalue) {
    $sth->execute(array(':Value' => $avalue, ':FormId'=> $FormId ));
    ++$FormId;
}
```

**[edit]** As per edit-suggestion by @AravindKishore, creating the prepared statement is better done before the loop. Prepare once, enjoy forever.